# Join of two streams not works

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to join two streams using Apache Flink streaming API but nothing is joined and I have no idea after reading docs, what I have done wrong

```
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
    DataStream<MyPojo2> source = env.fromCollection(Lists.newArrayList(new MyPojo2(1, "Ola"), new MyPojo2(2, "Ola")))
            .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new IngestionTimeExtractor<MyPojo2>());
    DataStream<MyPojo2> source2 = env.fromCollection(Lists.newArrayList(new MyPojo2(1, "Ela"), new MyPojo2(2, "Ela")))
            .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new IngestionTimeExtractor<MyPojo2>());
    DataStream<Tuple2<String, String>> joined = source.join(source2).where(keySelector).equalTo(keySelector).
            window(GlobalWindows.create()).apply(joinFunction);
    joined.print();
    env.execute("Window");
```

Key function is simply `myPojo.getFirst()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GlobalWindows` window never fires unless you specify a custom `Trigger`. In your example, if you use something like `TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5))` you should see results.

Comment: Therefore is there any way to have a two streams joined on their full history, using streaming API? I wouldn't like to use batch API because I'd like to get first result asap, but maybe there is some parameter for tuning batch API.

Comment: Joining them on their full history is not possible, since they are (technically) infinite streams. You can specify a Trigger that fires periodically with a given interval. This way you would join what is currently there. For that you would use `ContinuousProcessingTimeTrigger.of(Time.minutes(40))`, for example. If you want to remove the contents when triggering you can also wrap it in a `PurgingTrigger`.